# how to access superviewcontroller from its subviewcontroller in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have a viewcontroller and i am adding a subviewcontroller in that. Now i want to set value for a string from subviewcontroller which is in its superviewcontroller.

Please Suggest some idea

Thank You

Comment: you should not have added the title of question because all the below given answer has become wrong, you could either Change the content Or post a new question Thanks ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to access superview use the statement said by Jhaliya,
If you want to access superviewcontroller property frm subviewcontrller property ,
use

```
id mainViewController = [self.view.superview nextResponder];
```

here mainViewController is the superviewcontroller reference.

There a parentViewController property in UIViewController class reference,
This property is used for navigation, tab bar, and modal view controller hierarchies.

The above syntax is used for when you are setting a view as subview to a parentviewcontroller

Comment: There is a `parentViewController` property too.

Comment: @Deepak: hi, thank you, I updated the answer according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the super view controller using the `parentViewController` property on every UIViewController.

```
UIViewController *parent = self.parentViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [superview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW18) property of `UIView`.

```
UIMyView* mySuperView =  (UIMyView*) myView.superview ;
mySuperView.mytextString = @"Assign string to super view";
```

**EDITED:**

You could get the list of all your `UIViewController` by using methods of `UINaigationController` .
Also current visible controller and top view controller,

Read the documentation for [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) .

Comment: thank you for the answer. your answer is right for UIView. actually i am looking for viewController. so please check the question i have changed it and give some answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use superView method of UIView to access its parrent.

```
UIView *mySuperView = [MySubView superView];
```

Comment: actually my question is for viewController not for view. i have changed my question. please check. and suggest an idea.